# Class label values from nominal to numeric

Tags: class, dataset, label, weka, data-mining

How can i change the nominal values of the class label of a dataset to make them numeric?
e.g if my class labels are {iris-setosa,iris-virginica,iris-versicolor} i wanna make them iris-setosa=0, iris-virginica=1, iris-versicolor=2. So my instances values at the class label column should have values (0,0,1,2,2,0)?